# why switch statement always going to the default value?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Ok I looked up everything and even tried trimming my input. But no matter what I do, my switch statement keeps defaulting to the default statement.
But when the alphanum results as FALSE, it shows that error message ALONG with the default error message as well. It ends up showing BOTH of them.. which doesn't make sense as CASE statements are usually only one result...

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

```
function match_pattern($str, $pattern) {
        $pattern = trim($pattern);
        switch($pattern) {
            case 'alphanum':
                if( ! preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9]{1,}$/', $str))
                {
                    //error message must be same as function name
                    $this->set_message('match_pattern', 'The %s field must only contain alpha-characters or numbers!');
                    return false;  //failed
                }
                break;
            case 'numeric':
                if( ! preg_match('/^[0-9]{,}%/', $str)) {
                    $this->set_message('match_pattern', 'The %s field must only contain numeric characters!');
                    return false; //failed
                }
                break;
            default:
                $this->set_message('match_pattern', 'Invalid pattern');
                return false;
        }
        return true;  //passed
    }
```

Then here is the thing that is calling it:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|match_pattern[alphanum]|min_length[3]|max_length[25]|is_unique[user.username]');
```

Yes this is CodeIgniter.. If the alphanum comes up as false (true in this case), it will show the error message. However if I type "lilmousiee", it doesn't show the error message because it passes the preg_match expression.
BUT no matter WHAT I type, it ALWAYS shows "Invalid Pattern" error message. Sometimes it shows that AND the alphanum error message when I type "lilmousiee 6" since it doesn't allow spaces. How is it still displaying the default value and another one at the same time?.. Something isn't right here...

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only way both "The %s field must only contain alpha-characters or numbers!" and "Invalid pattern" would be for this function to be called more than once.  I'd be curious to know what you see if you append $str and $pattern to the output messages.

Comment: OMG you're right O_O I had a match_pattern[alpha_num_space], but never made that argument D: OMG THANK YOU!!

Comment: You should post that as an answer and close the question

Answer (score 0):

@femtoRgon was correct! I had a match_pattern[alpha_num_space], but had no case statement for that so it was defaulting as well!
Hence the reason it showed two error messages sometimes!

Thank you!